# Is it ever correct to omit periods at the ends of paragraphs?

Tags: punctuation, periods

I encountered this claim from a user on cooking who seems to consistently remove periods at the ends of paragraphs:

> Never use them. They have no place on electronic media, they are a legacy device?

And later:

> End of paragraph periods were for bad typing/handwriting spacing. Computers format very cleanly, so no purpose, and they look weird on sentences that end in URL's or emoticons etc

Is there any broad or authoritative or "real" support for that idea?

Comment: Not that I know of ***.***

Comment: Very strange place.  The person who doesn't like periods at the end of paragraphs thinks there's something called "Particle Theory" that explains why warm water is better for washing dishes than cold water.  Another poster in that thread thinks that soap kills bacteria.  The first person evidently thinks that periods at the end of paragraphs are a superfluous typesetting artifact like placing two spaces after a period at the end of a sentence.  The rest of the world understands that periods by useful convention end written sentences.  Readers will wonder whether something has been omitted.

Comment: @deadrat Let's not get into the business of discussing the cooking (ish) aspects of that post; I linked purely to make the full discussion visible in case it added anything and to provide the post as an example. If you want to try to address anything in those answers, you can comment there! It feels a bit behind the back here.

Comment: @deadrat Whether or not this is grammatically correct has nothing to do with whether that answer is right about how the world works, and it *definitely* has nothing to do with what a completely different person wrote in a completely different answer to the same question. If you think the claim about terminal punctuation is wrong, by all means write an answer. If you just want to criticize other things that user said, go do it to his face. (Helpful tip though: "particle theory" appears to be a UK term for "matter is made of particles that move around", and that person is from NZ.)

Comment: It's just a comment.  Take it as some unsolicited advice:  don't pay attention to people who don't know what they're talking about.  You're free to regard it as worth what you paid for it. And, no, I don't intend to talk to such people face to face.  That's a fool's errand. .  This isn't a grammatical question; it's one about style. That means there isn't a "correct" answer, just answers that comport with manuals of style, which exist to help readers.  I've told you my judgment about how helpful the missing periods are.  Feel free to ignore that as well.

Comment: I stand corrected about particle theory, which apparently is what I'm used to calling statistical mechanics.  And, no, it wouldn't be much help in analyzing the efficacy of washing dishes with soap and water of different temperatures.  Too low a level.

Comment: @Jefromi: The user's use of punctuation is generally poor. As quoted in your question, they used a question mark to end a statement. They're not the first person on SE to claim that punctuation is dead, and they're just as wrong as the others who went before them. Try posting this as a comment to them: "You mghit as wel say seplilng is ded, its not rlleay kneeded, evry1 can udnerstnad badly splet snetences. Deosnt maen that gud seplilng isn't heplful thuogh."

Comment: Also it seems weird to say it's an issue with URLs (which should really [be formatted into nicer text](http://www.notawebsite.com)) and emoticons when they're not part of SE posts anyway, and I usually put them after the punctuation. :)

Comment: The first quote has 3 basic mistakes:  a comma splice, a plural verb with a singular device, and a declarative statement that ends with a question mark.  I recall learning about these in 7th grade.  So the person quoted lacks credibility.  And, indeed, omitting a period would be a mistake.

Comment: FWIW, they might be thinking of quoting punctuation when a quote continues from one paragraph to the next.

Comment: They're also conflating two issues. It _is_ awkward to use a period with a sentence that ends with an emoticon or URL, but it's probably even more awkward to arrange your writing so that every such sentence appears at the end of a paragraph. (And for ending a paragraph with an emoticon I would just put it after the period anyway).

Comment: @deadrat - `Another poster in that thread thinks that soap kills bacteria` - uh, of course they do. Soap breaks down fats, including bacterial cell lipid walls, thus killing bacteria. That's a primary function of a soap.

Comment: @deadrat I do understand what you're saying. But I'm a moderator there. If I'm going to lay down the law and force someone to accept edits to their posts after attempts to roll back, I'm going to do it purely based on those edits, not anything else about that user. This question is about genuinely making sure I'm right about punctuation.

Comment: I'm going to speak my last here (and just about punctuation) lest I become That Internet Guy Who Has to Have the Last Word.  Punctuation is a matter of style, not grammar.  Thus there's no need to lay down any law because there isn't any right or wrong, only conformance or no to a style guide.  I doubt you have or enforce one of those.  Reasonable people with different guides disagree, and the guides themselves grant considerable leeway.  Punctuation is there to lead readers to the proper parsing of written text.  One person's superfluousness is another's necessity.

Comment: @deadrat I definitely get what you're saying there, and I'm a big defender of people's right to personal style. But there's a line somewhere - we want the posts on our sites to be easily readable and satisfy readers' basic expectations, so you can't use absolutely *any* style you want. There's a difference between "reasonable people/guides disagree" and "no one else does this".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think any authority supports it.

The idea has been discussed before; here's a Language Log post that talks about the issue: [Aggressive periods and the popularity of linguistics](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=8667). It links to this New Republic article: [The Period Is Pissed](https://newrepublic.com/article/115726/period-our-simplest-punctuation-mark-has-become-sign-anger), by Ben Crair, from which I took the following extracts:

> In my text messages and online chats [...] people use
>   the period not simply to conclude a sentence, but to announce “I am
>   not happy about the sentence I just concluded.”

Near the end:

> And these newfangled, emotional uses of terminal punctuation haven't
>   crossed over into more traditional, thoughtful writing.

I think Stack Exchange posts are more like online newspaper articles or blog posts, and not so much like text or chat messages.

(Another Language Log article with some comments and links: [Anticipatory confirmation](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=21548))

(The practice of omitting a period specifically in paragraph-final position has also been discussed on the [WordReference forums](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/omitting-a-full-stop-at-end-of-sentence-in-paragraphs.2362088/).)

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't actually thought to compare this to text and IM since nothing else here (in that post or otherwise) is at all like a text. That does make it make a bit more sense at least, but as you say that's not really the right model for a Stack Exchange post!

Comment: If you want to get super technical, your first quoted paragraph there ends with a quotation mark instead of a period.

Comment: @BradleyUffner If you're talking about in the question, that's not a paragraph from the answer with the missing periods, it's just a comment from the author trying to explain why they're missing.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it is ever correct to omit a period (or full stop) at the end of a normal English sentence or indeed a paragraph. 
But that is not to say that I don't see it "in the wild", and indeed, am guilty of omitting correct punctuation in a few cases *where the sense is clear even without it*.
I would omit a period at the end of a "sentence" that uses non-English words such as a fragment of code or a mathematical formula where any extraneous characters could lead to confusion or syntax problems. Example:

To fix the problem, use the switch **/persistent:yes**

Another example, in a presentation (ie projected on screen, PowerPoint, prezi, Keynote or whatever), I might use a series of bullet points without a closing period on any of them, not even the last. (I know! Heresy! Burn me as a witch!)
The next bullet usually makes the sense clear enough. The fragmented nature of the bullets often means they don't properly parse as a sentence anyway. In a formal text such as software documentation or training manual I would more usually ensure grammatical completeness.

To demonstrate as a meta-example, there are four reasons for this:

- it is just as comprehensible
- the next bullet arguably serves the same purpose as a separator
- I find it easier to be consistent in omitting them than including them
- everyone else seems to get away with it

Comment: In these cases (code etc), I would A) put a space before the period, and/or B) ensure that the code is in a distinct text format (bold, underline, `code`) that the period doesn't share. What if you don't have a "next bullet" and have to do this in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: @Random832 - I, like AdamV, tend to omit fullstops in bulleted lists. If there's no next bullet, and it's in the middle of a paragraph, I'll start the next line with a capital letter if it's a new sentence, or just continue on with a lower case letter if the list is in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Text in PP presentations often isn't even complete sentences, so normal punctuation rules may not even apply.

Answer (score 6):

The period signifies the end of a thought. The lack of a period at the end of a paragraph would tell me the thought, as a unit, is not complete.

The only acceptable omission of puncuation I've ever seen is the final quotation mark if the next paragraph is a continuation of the character's dialog.

Answer (score 0):

No «authority» would declare today that it is correct to omit the period of the last sentence of a paragraph.

However it seems that there is some usage of this phenomenon. The comic [Oglaf](https://www.oglaf.com/) (NSFW) omits the period of the last sentence in a speech bubble.

[image]

Another one is texting.

Perhaps rules of usage are slowly changing. What is simply not allowed now will be bad style only, and what is bad style now will be accepted style later. After all, rules follow usage, too. If enough people do something it will become the rule.

Comment: The example shown omits all full stops, it only has commas and other sentence-end marks (question, exclamation).

Answer (score -2):

Periods get lost in text (are hard to read on-screen at small fonts) -- so I have begun using two dashes to separate thoughts regardless whether it is correct punctuation or not -- clarity trumps correctness every time in my book.